# Updating nested values in MongoDB (Mongoose)

Tags: json, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried to update the nested value `data1` inside of the MongoDB document:

```json
{
  "content": {
    "data": {
      "data1": "Some data",
      "data2": "Better data"
    },
    "location": {
      "coordinates": [
        45,
        45
      ],
      "type": "Point"
    }
  },
  "_id": "647e40c590bc322763bdf182",
  "title": "test",
  "description": "Here is some updated description",
  "tags": [
    "test",
    "pic",
    "newTag"
  ],
  "dataType": "NOTREFERENCED",
  "createdAt": "2023-06-05T20:08:37.345Z",
  "updatedAt": "2023-06-07T18:37:23.134Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

however, I cannot get it working. I am using `mongoose` and I have tried the following options:

```js
const id = "647e40c590bc322763bdf182"

await this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{ $set: {content.data.data1: "Updated value"}},{new: true,});

await this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{ content.data.data1: "Updated value"},{new: true,});
```

Comment: What output/errors are you getting? So long as you wrap `content.data.data1` in quotation marks then your example seems to work perfectly fine in [this playground demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eXyhS_sP8nF)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import YourModel from './models/yourModel';

const id = "647e40c590bc322763bdf182";

const updateItem = async () => {
  try {
    const item = await YourModel.findById(id);

    if (!item) {
      const newItem = new YourModel({
        // ...
      });
      await newItem.save();
      return;
    }

    item.content.data.data1 = "Updated value";
    await item.save();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
  }
};

updateItem();
```

In this approach, we are first searching for the item and then modify its properties individually.

You can also try this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import YourModel from './models/yourModel';

const id = "647e40c590bc322763bdf182";

const updateItem = async () => {
  try {
    const updatedItem = await YourModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id },
      { $set: { 'content.data.data1': 'Updated value' } },
      { new: true, upsert: true }
    );

    console.log("Item updated:", updatedItem);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
  }
};

updateItem();
```

This uses `findOneAndUpdate` method from mongoose.

Let me know if this helped you.